# how to use one decimal in jquery using regular expression

Tags: jquery

I want use only one decimal and only number in input type.so i am using jquery but problem is he is taking more decimal?????
i want to like this:123.1245454
not to 12345.12245.4554

```
$('#edit-discount').keyup(function() {
        var $th = $(this);
        $th.val($th.val().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, function(str) {
            $("#req-productdis").hide();
            $("#alpha1").show();
            return '';
        }));
```

Comment: *"how to use one decimal.."*  Start with 'How to use one question mark'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

work around for finding more than one decimal dot in a field having decimal value. Cannot find the regression.
You can use the following code:

```
function checkDot(textVal) {
    var amount = textVal.val();
    var dots = amount.split(".").length;
    if (dots > 2) {

        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Match with `\d+\.?(\d+)?` and discard all the rest.

Answer (score 0):

See if this does it for you.

```
alert(parseFloat('12345.12245.4554'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var n = '12345.12245.4554';
n = n.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''); // trim to just numbers and dots
n = n.replace(/\./, 'x'); // note: NOT global - replaces first dot with x
n = n.replace(/\./g, ''); // note: global replace - remove all other dots
n = n.replace(/x/, '.'); // swap x back to .
alert(n);
```